# Filter in MongoDB is not working

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to filter data using a regex pattern from mongoDb and sort it by descending order.

```
var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Regex(Property, new BsonRegularExpression("/^[0-9 - _ ! @ # $ % ^ & * (`~)?/+<|>.{}]/"));

var SortBy = Builders<TDocument>.Sort.Descending(_ => _.Contact.Accounts.Name);

var Data= await db.GetCollection<TDocument>().Find(filter).Sort(SortBy).Limit(10).Skip(20)).ToListAsync();
```

Data is returning zero. Even though my collection has data that is matching that filter. And the total number of documents are 2.4k.

I have created an index using the following code:

```
  var indexUniqueIdDesc = Builders<TDocument>.IndexKeys.Descending(Property);
  await db.GetCollection<TDocument>(collection).Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexUniqueIdDesc, new CreateIndexOptions<TDocument>{ Background = true, Sparse = true });
```

Am I not getting the data, as this is issue of index creation, or because of the large amount of data, or have I written the query incorrectly?

Comment: Can you provide us with the mongo query itself? As far as I can see the issue has to be with the regex expression you are building.

Comment: with this regex without creating index it is working ok. It is returning documents matching that filter

Comment: Remove the enclosing `/` from the pattern-string you pass to the BsonRegularExpression - that is Javascript Syntax for a Regex, you should just pass the pattern: `new BsonRegularExpression("^[0-9 - _ ! @ # $ % ^ & * (`~)?/+<|>.{}]")`

Comment: Its not working . I removed /